# decltype e ponteiros

Tags: c++

Queria saber porque, que quando uso decltype(*pointer) - usando um ponteiro - ele define o tipo da variavel como referencia, exemplo:

```
int i = 42, *p = &i;
decltype(*p) c = i;
```

O que quero que entendam na minha pergunta é o seguinte:
Agora c é uma referencia(vinculada a i), mas porquê ele é uma referência e não um inteiro plano? Estou lendo o livro Cpp Primer 5th. Edition (pág. 110) diz isso e não entendo.

Answer (score 1):

As regras do especificador `decltype` estão aqui: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

O seu caso cai em uma expressão qualquer (terceiro item), pois `*p` não é uma [id-expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers), nem um [acesso de membro de classe](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access), e sim uma expressão qualquer.

> 3. If the argument is any other expression of type `T`, and
>
>    a. if the value category of expression is xvalue, then decltype yields `T&&`;
>
>    b. if the value category of expression is lvalue, then decltype yields `T&`;
>
>    c. if the value category of expression is prvalue, then decltype yields `T`.

A categoria de valor da expressão `*p` ([expressão de indireção](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_indirection_operator)) é definida como um [lvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue):

> The following expressions are lvalue expressions:
>
> - …
> - `*p`, the built-in indirection expression;

Portanto, o tipo em que `decltype(*p)` resulta vem da regra 3.b.: *if the value category of expression is lvalue, then decltype yields `T&`*, onde `T` é o tipo da expressão `*p`, que nesse caso é `int`. Substituindo, temos `int&` como o tipo resultante.